# Task not serializable when class is serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have the following class in Scala

```
case class A
  (a:Int,b:Int) extends Serializable
```

when I try in Spark 2.4. (via Databricks)

```
val textFile = sc.textFile(...) 
val df = textFile.map(_=>new A(2,3)).toDF()
```

(Edit: the error happens when I call df.collect() or register as table)

I get `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

what am I missing?

I've tried adding encoders:

```
implicit def AEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[A] = 
  org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[A]
```

and

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
```

edit: I have also tried:

```
val df = textFile.map(_=>new A(2,3)).collect()
```

but no luck so far.

Comment: real cluster or community edition? what is the point actually of this?

Comment: @thebluephantom community edition.  This just a sample I have a complex data type that gets pulled through regular expressions etc.  Otherwise I need to create an array of columns (20+), map columns manually.  I thought using a Type was a simple thing?!

Comment: I cannot get the error, just trying on CE as well. I did not need new either. Restart the cluster and try again, I have had this error sometimes and after restart it did not occur. Task not Serializable that is. Can you confirm ?

Comment: I am waiting for 5.

Comment: @thebluephantom I still get the error but when I call collect or register as a table.

Comment: Odd I see no issue.

Comment: @thebluephantom I presume it'd work fine on a local rather than a cluster but can't confirm.  don't know how to achieve that config in databricks.

Comment: Community Edition is local afaik. You can get most errors in CE. To prove on Cluster you need to upgrade. collect not an issue either.

Comment: just picked a new cluster.  Working now.

Comment: strange stuff.  Can you write your comment as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Proves my point.

Comment: Will do, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this occurs intermittently on DataBricks. Most annoying.

Restart the cluster and try again, I have had this error sometimes and after restart it did not occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly parse the file as `Dataset` with the case class you have.

```
case class A(a:Int,b:Int) extends Serializable
val testRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///test_file.csv")
val testDS = testRDD.map( line => line.split(",")).map(line_cols => A(line_cols(0).toInt, line_cols(1).toInt) ).toDS()

#res23: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[A] = [a: int, b: int]
```

Comment: that's what I'm aiming for but I get Task not serializable when I call collect or register table

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error, works fine for me on the Databricks cluster.